# OpenMPI 1.4.3 vs. Intel MPI Efficiency question

Tags: compiler-construction, performance, mpi, parallel-processing

I noticed that the exact same code took 50% more time to run on OpenMPI than Intel. I use the following syntax to compile and run:

**Intel MPI Compiler: Redhat Fedora Core release 3 (Heidelberg), Kernel version: Linux 2.6.9-1.667smp x86_64**

```
 mpiicpc -o xxxx.cpp <filename> -lmpi
```

**OpenMPI 1.4.3: (Centos 5.5 w/ python 2.4.3, Kernel version: Linux 2.6.18-194.el5 x86_64)**

```
 mpiCC xxxx.cpp -o <filename
```

MPI run command:

```
 mpirun -np 4 <filename>
```

**Other hardware specs**

```
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 15
model           : 3
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(TM) CPU 3.60GHz
stepping        : 4
cpu MHz         : 3591.062
cache size      : 1024 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 2
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 1
apicid          : 0
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 5
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36    
clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm syscall lmconstant_tsc pni monitor ds_cpl est tm2   
 cid xtpr
 bogomips        : 7182.12
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 128
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Can the issue of efficiency be deciphered from the above info? Does the compiler flags have an effect on the efficiency of the simulation. If so, what flags maybe useful to check to be included for Open MPI. Will including MPICH2 increase efficiency in running simulations using OpenMPI?

Comment: what is serial speed difference?

Comment: Serial with the intel compiler took 30% more time than the intel mpi version.

Comment: @ Anycorn: gcc took 3 times longer than the intel icpc compiler on serial.

Comment: You mention that the OpenMPI library took 50% longer to run than the Intel MPI.  What is the absolute times of each run?  Until runs get into the ~1000 second range, percentage differences in times are not necessarily meaningful.  For instance, 10seconds and 15seconds is a 50% change...but is better thought of as "5 seconds".

Comment: The test case looks to be run on a single machine.  It is *very* hard to beat Intel compiler/mpi running on Intel chips with anything else.  In particular, Intel does a LOT of memcpy optimization's that are accessible to other MPI implementations.  Also, what MPI calls are made by the application?  It is possible that Intel MPI is just better optimized than OpenMPI for the MPI calls, message sizes, and shared memory interface.

Comment: @semiuseless: Thanks for the response. I am using simple blocking  MPI Send and Recv. Also, the same program on one node with 4 slots, completed in 7 hours on Intel MPI vs. 12 hours using OpenMPI

Answer (score 1):

Is OpenMPI configured to use the same compiler as Intel MPI compiler? Your OpenMPI maybe using gcc, which explains the difference. If OpenMPI is using the same compiler as the Intel MPI compiler, make sure the compiler optimization flags used by both are identical.

Comment: @ Powerrox: As I indicated to Anycorn, the gcc compiler took 3 times longer than the intel icpc compiler to run the serial code. Coming to MPI, the Intel MPI was built on a Redhat Fedora Core release 3 OS while the OpenMPI uses a Centos 5.5 OS. Also, In the case of the Intel MPI compiler, I used mpiicpc -o xxx.cpp <file> -lmpi whereas, when I used OpenMPI, I used mpiCC -o file.cc <file>. I guess the only optimization flag common between the two was the "-o". I did not include the -lmpi in OpenMPI. Does my response make sense. I am still trying to resolve this as we wish to move to OMPI..

Comment: @Ashmohan, differences in runtimes for gcc & icpc or anything else is normal. You have to dig deeper to ensure both the compilers are using the same level of optimization etc. You also have to make sure both the compilers fully support the architecture you are using to execute you code on. I dont see it as a concern, but an exercise everyone has to go through.

Comment: @Ashmohan, The compilers you are using to compile your MPI code are just wrappers that setup & call the actual compiler. And the wrappers themselves will pass certain optimization flags to the compiler. Its hard for me to describe the details in comments. I think you are very new to this (MPI) and you need to narrow down your question and/or do some more reading. Sorry couldnt help more.